# Migrate project to gradle build system error

Tags: android, gradle, migrate

I'm getting a "Migrate project to gradle build system" error when I tried to import an Eclipse project to my Android studio.

This is the error I get:

[image]

This is my Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Right click on eclipse project and Export project as gradle and than use it in android studio.

Comment: This might sound silly but I can't find any 'export' option. Where to find and how do I do this?

Comment: I have added it in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Open your eclipse from where you need to export the project:
1. Right click on project -> Export

[image]

2. On Export dialog Export project as gradle.

[image]

I Hope it works now. Feel free to ask for any query.